# octave function wavread cannot open wav file

Tags: file, audio, octave, wav

I am attempting to use octave to read a .wav file into a vector array for other analysis, but when I try to run the script, octave cannot open the file.

The code is:

```
[S,fs] = wavread('snare.wav');
plot(S);
```

Upon running the script, I get the following error:

```
error: audioinfo: failed to open file snare.wav
wavread at line 91 column 8
analysis_1 at line 1 column 7
```

I have the 'snare.wav' file in the same directory as the script file 'analysis_1.m', so the compiler should be able to find the .wav file. It is just that octave cannot open the file.

I am running ubuntu on a Dell XPS.

Any help would be appreciated. Should I try to reinstall octave?

Thanks community

Comment: try using either full path as in   `/some/path/here/snare.wav`     or to harden the relative path try   wavread('./snare.wav');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the file `snare.wav` is in the same directory as the file `analysis_1.m`. The importand point is, that the wave file is in the "current directory" when waveread is called with `'snare.wav'`. This is important if you change directories with `cd` in your script or you call scripts and functions with realtiive paths or add them via `addpath`. I'll show you the last one as example.

Consider following structure:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── bar.m
    └── myfile
```

the file bar.m only consists of `stat myfile`

If you now navigate to `foo` with `cd` and call `bar` you get as result

```
octave:1> bar
ans =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    dev =  2065
    ino =  5672946
    mode =  33188
    modestr = -rw-r--r-- 
    nlink =  1
    uid =  1000
    gid =  1000
    rdev = 0
    size =  6
    atime =    1.5196e+09
    mtime =    1.5196e+09
    ctime =    1.5196e+09
    blksize = 0
    blocks =  8
```

But if you, for example use `addpath` and you are outside foo:

```
octave:1> addpath ("foo")
octave:2> bar
ans = [](0x0)
```

the file isn't found.

So to debug your code, just add `pwd` and `ls` directly before your `waveread`
and check if they met your expectation or add a `keyboard` and debug from this

Comment: Got it now. Using the full path did finally fix the problem. I understand the 'working directory' better now. Thanks